# Angular 2 Interface property mapping

Tags: angular, interface, observable

Could someone please help me to understand this. The tutorials that I learned Angular 2 from demonstrated using an interface to store date via an Observable. ie: .map((response: Response) =>  response.json()).

The one issue I have found is that my interface property definitions must match the json properties exactly. ie; If the json propety is _custNum my interface must use the same exact name _custNum. If I were to change the name to 'custNum' it will not map. Is this just the rule with interfaces?

Sample code:

```
export interface ICustSearch {
     _custNum:  string;
     _custName: string;
     _address: string;
     _city: string;
     _state: string;
     _zip: string;
     _county: string;
     _phone: string;
 }

 return this._http.get(APIRoutes.custSearchLocal, {headers: headers})
             .map((response: Response) => <ICustSearch[]> 
                         response.json())
             .catch(this.handleError);
```

Now If I would change the property '_custNum' in the above interface to 'custNum' the map would fail on the customer number.  Is there a work around for this.  Also, why use interfaces vs a class for mapping json objects, what's the advantage?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Both questions are not related to Angular but TypeScript.

In general it is cast mechanism in TypeScript to validate that any Object follows provided convention (Interface/Class). And you can use Classes, but if your class/interface has declared Methods, provided Object must implement all of them (which you definitely cannot do with JSON), otherwise TypeScript compiler wouldn't allow you to cast... There are number of techniques to convert any Object to Class (i.e. extend Class Instance with Object, using constructors, setters, converters).

And for sure you can avoid Classes/Interfaces and use just `any` type...

And yes, there is no built in way to cast properties with different names, unless you implement/find implementation, which might be another Converter/Factory.

It might be good idea having similar to JPA Domains way to assign list of aliases for each Interface/Class property, but most of the times API changes not so frequently plus you can find tons of JSON to TypeScript Interface online generators.

Comment: A. Tim:  Thanks for the response.  Sorry for marking this as Angular, I am very new to Angular and Typescript.  I will continue my questions marked as Typescript